# How to Create a Public Storage w/ HTTP Endpoint Azure

Tags: http, azure, storage

Any blob, container, or storage account in Windows Azure is created with HTTPS. But for VMDepot I need to have a public HTTP endpoint.

How can this be created or configured using the Cross Platform CLI or the management portal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All storage accounts support both HTTPs and HTTP endpoints.  All you need to do is access the URL with HTTP protocol.